# Maximum File Upload Size Error In ASP.NET Razor site

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix-2

I have built a video site using Webmatrix 2 but when I try and upload a min of two videos .webm and .mp4 (in this case both files add up to about 34mb) I get this error...
"The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length."

The site is running locally on my machine with an instance of IIS 8. I have tried adding Maxrequest and executeTimeout without any luck.

```
     web.config <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000" executionTimeout="600" />
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 2000000 bytes is less than 34MB

Comment: What's the maximum you can add that will cope with my 34MB?

Comment: Given a kilobyte is 1024 bytes, and a megabyte is 1024 kilobytes, the calculation is simple.

Comment: Ok, I have increased the maxRequestLength to more than cover my 34MB still get the error.

Comment: What is the number you are using now?

Comment: Well I changed the config file to <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="34816" />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24885/discussion-between-nickp-and-leppie)

Comment: You need to multiply it with 1024 again, like I explained. 34816 is only 32 kilobytes.

Comment: Ok I wasn't hoping for a maths lesson but a solution to the file upload error would be great. Thus 1024 * 1024*34 gives us 35651584? Which is what I have in my config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested I applied the following that sorted it out.

[Read this article that explains it well:](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits)

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
 </system.webServer>
```